# comparator not working for large data in Hadoop streaming in python

Tags: python, sorting, hadoop-streaming

ran this command for sorting data:
 -D  mapreduce.job.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.KeyFieldBasedComparator \
 -D mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options=-k1n,2n \

i can see in my reducer same keys are present ,but they are not in sorted order

format is key(field1) \t key(field2)|value-delimited by |
It's running for small data set but when i take large data set data is getting partitioned but not sorted.Can any body help?

Comment: I ran command for hadoop streaming .My mappers and reducers file is in python

Comment: Can you show your command and sample of input and output?